# Cookies not being sent on initial mobile device app launch (works in web browser)

Tags: angular, cookies, ionic4

When previewing my app on a mobile device (via Xcode) for the first time, my authentication cookie isn't being sent to the server.

I login with my username/password and can see the cookie being sent by the server (via [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)), but subsequent requests don't have the cookie attached, so the server response with a 401.

If I close and re-open the app, everything works fine. It's only on the initial launch of the app that this issue occurs.

This issue doesn't occur in Chrome of Firefox web browsers.

I've looked online and found [this issue posted on the Ionic GitHub](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/14674) which appears to be the same problem, but the issue was closed stating that it was a support request, not a bug.

I've looked on the Ionic forums but haven't found anyone with the same issue.

My initial thought was that maybe I wasn't using `withCredentials: true`, but I've double checked my `HttpInterceptor` and it's 100% there (plus, it's only on the initial load of the app that this issue arises. Closing the app and re-opening it resolves the issue).

I expect the session cookie to be sent with every request when the app is initially loaded onto a device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue using the following : https://github.com/CWBudde/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-inject-cookie